# Why can Java auto-convert a byte to most other primitives in return of a function?

Tags: java, return, byte, return-value

Perhaps this is something I overlooked back when I learned the basics of Java, but why is the following code legal?

```
float foo(byte b) {
    return b;
}
```

It is allowed with every primitive type, with the exception of char and boolean.

Comment: There are rules defined in the JLS for how data types can be widen.  Note: `float` (32-bit) is considered wider than `long` (64-bit)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> It is allowed with every primitive type, with the exception of char
>   and boolean.

For boolean YES, but for `char` to `float` - it is **allowed**. *(EDIT)* As per your comment, `byte` to  `char` is not in the list and its not allowed.

You should see: [5.1.2. Widening Primitive Conversion](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.2)

> 19 specific conversions on primitive types are called the widening
>   primitive conversions:
>
> - **byte to short, int, long, float, or double**
> - short to int, long, float, or double
> - char to int, long, float, or double
> - int to long, float, or double
> - long to float or double
> - float to double
>
> A widening primitive conversion does not lose information about the
>   overall magnitude of a numeric value.

Comment: Thanks for the prompt answer, exactly the info I needed. However, it does not work with `char` for me, it throws compile-time error.

Comment: @b1naryatr0phy, what is the error you are getting, also see `A narrowing conversion of a char to an integral type T likewise simply discards all but the n lowest order bits, where n is the number of bits used to represent type T. In addition to a possible loss of information about the magnitude of the numeric value, this may cause the resulting value to be a negative number, even though chars represent 16-bit unsigned integer values.` from the same link

Comment: The compile error I'm getting (in Eclipse) is `Type mismatch: cannot convert from byte to char`

Comment: @b1naryatr0phy,  oh I thought you were trying to convert from `char` to `float`, that is allowed, but not `char` to `byte`, byte is 8 bits, `char` is 16 bits, `byte` can't accomodate `char`, hence the error.

Comment: Not `char` to `byte`, `byte` to `char`. In the example I posted, I can change the `return` value to anything but `boolean` and `char`. But perhaps this is because `char` doesn't specifically fall under the _widening primitive conversions_ list you provided.

Comment: @b1naryatr0phy,  `char to int, long, float, or double` - but not byte

Comment: No no, I understand that, I'm talking about `byte` **to** `char`

Comment: @b1naryatr0phy, Yes. You are right, byte to char is not there in the list and its not allowed.